# Desktop folders deleted and how to recover

Tags: macos-highsierra, qbittorrent

I created a torrent in qbittorent and saved it on the desktop . When I deleted it some folders also got deleted .
What I basically did was created torrent of desktop itself by mistake .
How can I recover these folders . Please help .

Comment: Use file recovery software of your choice.  Depending on the size of files you removed, and how much data you have written since their deletion, will determine your chances recovering the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) it's free and easy, but the more you wait there are less chances to recover anything